# I have multiple storyboards. How can I use AppDelegate to open another ViewController in another storyboard? (Segue)

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

Here is the code I have. I have tried a few different approaches and some of them gives me the error that the view is not in the hierarchy.

The code snippet below goes in the correct else but can't perform the segue or presentViewController

```
func applicationDidTimout(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let vc = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        if let myTableViewController = vc.visibleViewController as? AccountsOverviewViewController {
            // Call a function defined in your view controller.
            myTableViewController.signOffUser()
        } else {
            // We are not on the main view controller. Here, you could segue to the desired class. 
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Accounts", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AccountsNavigationController") as UIViewController
            let vc2 = getVisibleViewController(nil)
            vc2?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}

func getVisibleViewController(var rootViewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {

    if rootViewController == nil {
        rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    }

    if rootViewController?.presentedViewController == nil {
        return rootViewController
    }

    if let presented = rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
        if presented.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController) {
            let navigationController = presented as! UINavigationController
            return navigationController.viewControllers.last!
        }

        if presented.isKindOfClass(UITabBarController) {
            let tabBarController = presented as! UITabBarController
            return tabBarController.selectedViewController!
        }

        return getVisibleViewController(presented)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Storyboard references, they are objects on the right like UILabel and you can link segues or call them from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the func below to get the visible view controller,

```
func getVisibleVC() -> UIViewController? {
  if var visibleVC = window?.rootViewController {
    while let presentedVC = visibleVC.presentedViewController {
      visibleVC = presentedVC
    }
    return visibleVC
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: Just a for-the-record: this doesn't work in OSX and you'll have to wire this manually using an ivar.

Comment: Thank you the problem was thet I couldn't get my VisibleVC